# How to get an array of all functions within a class in PHP?

Tags: php, class, function, reflection

How to get an array of all functions within a class in PHP?

Working in PHP 5.2.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [`ReflectionClass`](http://php.net/ReflectionClass)

```
$class = new ReflectionClass('ClassName');
$methods = $class->getMethods();
```

`$methods` will return an array of [`ReflectionMethod`](http://php.net/ReflectionMethod) objects, which you can then iterate through and get detailed information about each method:

```
foreach($methods as $method)
{
    // $method->getName()
    // $method->getParameters()
    // etc.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for get_class_methods():

http://il2.php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php